# A question about computation analysis

Tags: computational-complexity

I have derived that the required number of operations in my algorithm is $Y(a)$, where $a>0$ is the concerned parameter.

However, $Y(a)$ is not a closed-form expression w.r.t. $a$.

But I find that $Y(a)\leq P(a)$, and $P(a)$ can be expressed as a closed-form w.r.t. $a$, that is $P(a)=a^2+1$.

So, can I say that my algorithm has a computation complexity $\mathcal{O}(a^2)$?

If not, how can I describe the computation complexity?

Thanks for any helpful advice! ^v^

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364491

Comment: Thanks!
The suggested content greatly gives me the answer!